# I can ping facebook but get a time out error

Tags: dns, connection, ping, facebook

Yesterday I was on *facebook*: no problems I can get on with my phone but not on my PC.
I've tried other browsers.
I am on a home *PC POS Windows Vista* machine.

I have flushed DNS and I can ping facebook.
I get an IP Address of `173.252.120.61` and it works.
I have not downloaded any new add ons.

PS> I am barely computer literate, although I can look up fixes and follow step by step instructions.

Comment: When you say _I can get on with my phone but not on my PC_, do you mean your phone is connected with the wifi home network (the same of the PC computer)?

Answer (score 1):

Just some points:

```
host www.facebook.com
```

give as answer

```
www.facebook.com is an alias for star.c10r.facebook.com.
star.c10r.facebook.com has address 31.13.93.3
```

If you try you can *ping* to *31.13.93.3* and get an answer.

As you can check e.g. on [ipaddress](http://173.252.120.61.ipaddress.com/) *173.252.120.61* belongs effectively to *Facebook*, so it doesn't seems to be an [*IP spoofing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing).

However this do not means that the internal machine has to answer to your ping request.

Administrators can set internal machines to avoid to answer to ping request even to limit [DDos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) problems.

How to proceed... in many different ways; you have to understand why by attempt. So:

- First check if your mobile is connected on the same network of your pc.
- If you have another device that you can connect to your home network connection to internet use it to check if the problem is of the computer or of the network.
- Then check for the configuration of your computer, if you have some firewall active that excludes browsing of that IP group, or if you have some program that limits the internet browsing.
- Check for *malware* or virus.
- Try to start with a private session of firefox (or of another browser) that will not read anything from the cache.
- If all fails try to create a new user and to log in from it.
- If even this fails try to download and install on an usb pen drive a live version of an  operative system (e.g. Ubuntu): reboot on this and check on your new device...